# Nasm floating point reading and printing error

Tags: assembly, floating-point, nasm

This is the code I wrote for reading 2 floating point numbers and stored it in the memory. Then I load it from memory and print it. However, I'm getting wrong value for first number when printing it. But the I'm getting correct value for second number. I dont know what is going wrong in this code. Please help.

```
SECTION .data
message1: db "Enter the first number: ", 0
message2: db "Enter the second number: ", 0
formatin: db "%lf", 0
formatout: db "%lf", 10, 0 ; newline, nul terminator

section .bss
f1: resd 1
f2: resd 1

SECTION .text
global main 
extern scanf 
extern printf     

main:


push message1
call printf

add esp, 4 
push f1
push formatin 
call scanf
add esp, 8 

push message2
call printf
add esp, 4 

push f2
push formatin
call scanf
add esp, 8

fld qword[f1]
sub esp, 4
fst qword[esp]
push formatout
call printf
add esp, 8

fld qword[f2]
sub esp, 4
fst qword[esp]
push formatout
call printf
add esp, 8


mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use RESQ instead of RESD

```
f1: resq 1
f2: resq 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your going for double precission floating point numbers make the following changes.

```
section .bss
f1: resq 1      ;!!!
f2: resq 1      ;!!!
```

and also

```
fld qword[f1]
sub esp, 8      ;!!!
fst qword[esp]
push formatout
call printf
add esp, 12     ;!!!

fld qword[f2]
sub esp, 8      ;!!!
fst qword[esp]
push formatout
call printf
add esp, 12     ;!!!
```